# How to take care of Mammy Croton?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care

I got a beautiful Mammy Croton today. Unfortunately, I am completely new to gardening & plant care and was wondering how I am supposed to properly care for this plant. I have been reading about light preferences and watering frequency, but I still feel there are some clear gaps in my knowledge.

Here are my questions:

1. Is 4-5 hours of daily sunlight enough for this plant?
2. What about the cloudy or winter days with scanty sunlight?
3. Can it be kept near a night lamp?
4. How deep should the pot be?
5. Is a moisture meter required or simply using fingers should suffice?
6. What things should I be careful about when repotting?
7. What other factors can ensure a healthy growth and longevity of the plant?

Thanks all for your inputs!

Comment: Tropical plants need full tropical sun, not 5 hours, though I've seen crotons on the shadier side of greenhouses doing well. In Georgia, 5 hours will keep the plants alive but the riot of colors fading to green. Nothing besides sun matters much. They are outdoors in the Summer, right? Try more sun and see.